# Возможно ли преобразовать тип через значение переменной?

Tags: java

Возможно ли передать через переменную тип для приведения? 
 Вместо этого:

```
int x = (int) 9.8;
```

Можно ли сделать что-то вроде такого:

```
a = int; //что-то, что может хранить тип
int x = (a) 9.8;
```

Comment: Тип можно хранить в объекте класса `Class<T>`. то бишь примерно так: `Class<Integer> integerClass = Integer.TYPE;`.

Comment: можно записать в переменную `а` тип нужного класса, а потом обработать эту ситуацию через `instanceof` или сравнение `==` с типом нужного класса, но без использования явного приведения не обойтись!

Answer (score 0):

как уже ответили в комментариях, можно в переменную сложить класс, а потом используя метод [cast](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast-java.lang.Object-) привести объект в соответсвующий тип.

```
Class<MyType> a = MyType.class;
MyType x = a.cast(someObj);
```

но с примитивными типами (int, double, ...) это не работает, потому что тот каст, который вы привели в примере это не стандартное приведение типа, а [сужение примитивного типа](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)